# sklearn: Transfer learning from one DataFrame to predict another DataFrame using GridsearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, transfer-learning

I have two `pd.Dataframe`'s.
One is huge, the other is small.

Both dataframes have two columns, where one has text and the other the label being either  `0` or `1`. The column names are:

`X,Y` for the huge dataframe

and
`text, label` for the small one.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline    
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(max_features =  10000, min_df = 25)), 
        ('clf',  RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 2000, random_state=0, verbose = True, n_jobs=-1))
    ])
    parameters = {'clf__max_depth': [200, None], 'vect__max_df': [500, 5000]} 
    clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, scoring='average_precision').fit(X, Y) 
    predicted_label = clf.predict(text)
```

The output for

```
metrics.classification_report(label, predicted_label, target_names=["0","1"])
```

looks like this:

```
Metrics:                precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.86      1.00      0.92      3000
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       500

    accuracy                           0.86      3500
   macro avg       0.43      0.50      0.46      3500
weighted avg       0.74      0.86      0.79      3500
```

My questions:

- What changes can I make, so that in the transfer-learn approach it
  does not predict every text to be 0?
- What are possible reasons that it assumes all texts to be 0?
- Why does the GridsearchCV(scoring='') Parameter seem to have no effect when transfer learning?

  I would like to keep using the RandomForestClassifier if possible.

Comment: can u try splitting the X,Y into train,test set and see what happens on that test set? what is the ratio of 0 to 1 labels i.e. how balanced are classes?

Comment: Sure. The Ratio is 25000 to 500  (0 to 1). with Metrics:                precision    recall  f1-score   support
 
           0       0.99      1.00      0.99     25000
           1       0.94      0.50      0.65       500
 
    accuracy                           0.99     25500
   macro avg       0.97      0.75      0.82     25500
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     25500

Comment: so the result is lot better now, right? that suggests df2 and df1 have different distributions, so you might want to merge them, and then randomly split to train/test. Also, try balancing the dataset classes using [imblearn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Merging them might be worth a shot. I wasn't considering that until now, because I wanted to try and show, whether or not I can use data from df1 (big) to predict things in df2. As theres more data available for df1. But is there no way to fine tune anything in my current approach by changing settings?

Comment: the first thing I'd do is using `imblearn`, start with some simple method like SMOTE or BalancedRandomForest. Also the range of values for 'clf__max_depth' is pretty useless, use some lower values like `[4,8,16,32,64,None]`